# How to transfer android studio's local history from one version to the other?

Tags: android-studio

When I updated android studio, when going into the ide, my local history wasn't appearing, I have backed it up so when I went to move it to its new directory, in the new version, it kept being automatically wiped every time I tried starting android studio, is there a way of using the local history from an older android studio version on a new one or would I have to downgrade android studio back to its original version?

Comment: @Zoe no because that question has no answer to it.

Comment: @Zoe that question looks like it has been removed

Comment: @Tvde1 it was more or less the same question by OP. Self-deleted 6 minutes ago

Comment: @Tvde1 it was my question, but I didn't get an answer the first time so I tired rephrasing it.

Comment: In the future, please [edit] your question instead of reposting it.

Comment: @RyanM yeah well if I did that then I probably wouldn't have got an answer.

Comment: @john_smith have you fixed your issue, I'm facing the same problem here

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Here's a [possible workaround from this comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-61385#focus=Comments-27-4313080.0-0) - you have to copy/backup the whole Android Studio folder of the old version and then merge it with the new one - because the files in **Local History** internally use content from outside that folder

---

At this time it's not possible to use **Local History** created from a different version of the IDE. Your backed up copy of the history won't work with the new version it's considered corrupt and gets reset.

---

First let's identify what is **Local History**

> Local History helps you constantly track all changes made to a project independently of version control.

Since Android Studio is InteliJ based you can also find information about it in the InteliJ documentation:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/local-history.html

> Note that Local History is not a replacement for a proper version control for long-term versioning. **Local History is cleared when you install a new version of IntelliJ IDEA.**

This includes app updates

You can monitor the following ticket for more details and updates:

[Provide a way for the local history to "survive" VFS crash and Invalidate Caches and reinstallations](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-61385?_ga=2.82131731.449013234.1608559750-1601719832.1580286257)

---

It seem you rely on Local History to such extent that you even consider a downgrade to an older version, but as the authors of the IDE state:

> Local History is not a replacement for a proper version control for long-term versioning.

You would benefit much more to just use a regular versioning system to save significant checkpoints during development.

Comment: I do now, I use git but that's not my question, I have backed up the local history file and I want to get it to work in my new updated version.

Comment: I've answered that question too - it's not a matter of manually making a backup of the files - they won't work in another version of the IDE. If you're interested in details follow the links

Comment: so what downgrade the ide and then they will work?